nvim_buf_get_extmarks - way to get extmark id
I'm trying to retrieve existing extmarks by using nvim_buf_get_extmarks API.
the return type of this function is this:
--- @class vim.api.keyset.get_extmark_item
--- @field [1] integer row
--- @field [2] integer col
--- @field [3] vim.api.keyset.extmark_details?

However, I see that it used to also return id for each extmark before the row.
extmark_details don't have id either.
Is there a proper way to get extmark id?
Why did this API change?

AFAICT, it’s still documented as returning the id, but I might be wrong (browsing GitHub on mobile is… not fun)

Yeah, all LLMs also expect id in return, but it is different now: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/7381f0a1d517474dcf8d8d019cbda430ce4bff23/runtime/lua/vim/_meta/api_keysets_extra.lua#L46

After looking at the Neovim source, I think this is just a typo unless the other docs are not right:

examples in :help extmark show an ID return, as does :help nvim_buf_get_extmarks():
    Return: ~
        List of `[extmark_id, row, col]` tuples in "traversal order".


28d1640dd (feat: improve return type annotations for vim.api.*, 2024-01-26) didn't change the implementation, only added the doc comments used for what I assume is completion documentation.
The C implementation still says it returns an ID:
/// @return List of `[extmark_id, row, col]` tuples in "traversal order".
Array nvim_buf_get_extmarks(Buffer buffer, Integer ns_id, Object start, Object end,
                            Dict(get_extmarks) *opts, Arena *arena, Error *err)



I guess it's time for you to open a PR to update the docs :)

Thank you, yes, it looks like the documentation is wrong, will try to make a PR to update it.
